# "excepto yo" vs "excepto mí"

Tags: pronombres, sujeto

A translation of the English sentence "Nobody sang except **me**" into Spanish would be "Nadie cantó excepto **yo**". Why does the object pronoun in English become the subject pronoun in Spanish?

Comment: In Spanish, if A knocks on the door, and B asks, "¿Quién es?", the answer is "Soy yo."   But in English the answer is "It's me."  (As @eftshift0 pointed out, in English is *should* actually be "It is I" -- but at least in the U.S., in practice people don't say "It is I." )

Answer (score 2):

You certainly gave me food for thought. Maybe this trick will suffice to explain: rephrase to get the 'subjects' together:

> Nadie excepto yo cantó.

Music to my ears. I would say that Spanish is 'functionally consistent' in this case. Is the trick valid in English?

Nobody except I sang.

I think that sounds correct, but I'm not a native speaker so won't conclude on it. However when using *but* instead of *except* it really comes out: **nobody sang but I** / **Nobody but I sang'**... Which looks kind of weird but I would think those are the right way to use them, the same way one *should* answer **'it is I'** to the question of **'who is it?'**

PS 1: in grammatical terms, the use of 'yo' (subject pronoun) vs 'mi' (object pronoun) makes perfect sense because **I** is the person who carried out the act of singing (actually, the only one because no one else joined, right? ;)) So it is actually English the one that is kind of breaking it because Spanish (as I said before) is doing it consistently.